# PDF File Broken after download using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, download, header

I'm trying to generate and Download PDF Files. The generation and the storage on the server is working.

In the last step I want to force the download of the generated pdf file.

I'm using the following code:

```
$filename = "test.pdf";
$filepath = "path/to/file.pdf";

header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='".$filename."'");
readfile($filepath);
```

The download itself is working, however the pdf says: Error on loading the PDF-Document

I've tried other solutions with other headers (more detailed) and nothing seems to work... any ideas?

PS: The downloaded file isn't empty (Filesize ~20 KB which should be correct)

Update: The problem only occurs when running it on my local machine. Uploaded to a server it is working...

Comment: So if you download the PDF directly from the server without PHP in the way it opens fine?

Comment: Yes it does ... I can open it directly and it is working

Comment: Any chance you could provide the file that is not working?

Comment: as posted in the update of the question: it was due to the fact that i was running it on my local machine... online it's working now

Answer (score 1):

If downloading the PDF file directly from the server, without PHP in the way, results in a valid PDF then I would say it's highly likely that PHP is what's corrupting the downloaded file. The most likely cause is output from the error handler, like a notice or warning.

Best way to determine if this is the case is to comment out the `readfile` call and leave everything else in place. Then open the resulting file in a text editor and see what the output is, if any. If it is indeed errors from the error handler, you want to go ahead and fix those bugs first.

Additionally, there should be a space between the HTTP header name and value.

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='".$filename."'");
```

and not...

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='".$filename."'");
```

Comment: Without the readfile call it shouldnt know where the pdf is stored - or am i wrong?

Comment: The result was an completly empty file (without the readfile part)